# gwt dynamic adding textbox

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

```
 @UiHandler("addDynamicTextboxbutton")
  void addMoreTextbox(ClickEvent event) {


     textboxplaceholder.add(new TextBox(),"textboxplace");

 }
```

when addDynamicTextboxbutton button is clicked, this method is executed and new textbox is created.  how to have another button, so that when click, will get all the values from each of the "textbox()"  ? or is it necessary to put name "new textbox("name")" so that i can get all their values?  what is the best practice way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `textboxplaceholder` is and extend of a `ComplexPanel`, for example `FlowPanel` you could simply iterate over the children of the `FlowPanel`:

```
for (Widget w: textboxplaceholder) {
   if (w instanceof TextBox) {
     // do something value: ((TextBox)w).getValue();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a collection to store the newly added `TextBox` from which you can later get all the values. Something like this:

```
public class Test extends Composite {

    private static TestUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(TestUiBinder.class);

    interface TestUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Test> {}

    @UiField
    FlowPanel textboxplaceholder;
    @UiField
    Button addDynamicTextboxbutton;
    private LinkedList<TextBox> boxes;

    public Test() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        boxes = new LinkedList<TextBox>();
    }

    @UiHandler("addDynamicTextboxbutton")
    void addMoreTextbox(ClickEvent event) {
        TextBox box = new TextBox();
        textboxplaceholder.add(box);
        boxes.add(box);
    }
}
```

Iterate over the boxes stored in `boxes` to get all the values.